# What is the significance of the stick with the wolf face?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-wolfman

In *The Wolfman (2010) UNRATED*, I saw this stick with a wolf face in the hands of a passenger on a train. Then it goes into the hands of *Larry Talbot* and it goes into the hands of *Sir John Talbot*. And finally it appears in the hands of *Inspector Frederick*.

[image]

What is the significance of this stick?

Comment: It's been a while since I've seen the movie, so I don't recall a specific passenger on a train wielding the rod, however everyone else on that list is or will become infected by the Lycanthrope curse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literary Foreshadowing of the people cursed and symbolism for the curse of the wolf being passed on.